# Dynamic variables (in lexical analysis)

Tags: algorithm, parsing, interpreter, lexer

I learned about lexical and syntax analysis recently and I was thinking about dynamic variables.

Let say you have language syntax like this:

```
a = "1"
b%a# = 22
a = "2"
c%a# = 35
```

At the end memory should contain:
`a = "2"`, `b1 = 22`, `c2 = 35`

But it's unclear to me how would I implement this feature.

I would be grateful if someone share knowledge about this.

Answer (score 1):

"Dynamic" effectively means that it happens at runtime, not during compilation. So this feature won't be implemented during lexical analysis. What the parser (including lexical analyser) needs to do is to transform `b%a#` into a representation of the runtime operation "concatenate the string literal `b` with the current value of the variable `a` and make a dynamic variable reference from the result."

When this is executed, the runtime will most likely use some kind of hash table to look up dynamic variables by their name.